# How to execute macros from Android Programmatically?

Tags: android, macros, android-touch-event

I used this app [HiroMacro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prohiro.macro) to record touch events (which includes text input). This works fine, I can record and replay events. It gives a text file of recorded events, which is something like this:

```
start
touchDown 0 383 742
sleep 48
touchUp 0
sleep 1839
touchDown 0 461 997
sleep 100
touchUp 0
sleep 637
```

Now, I need to execute these from Android app, programmatically. Any idea how can this be done?

Are these C language macros?